# Question related to lemma 1.42 in Koralov & Sinai

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-68829-7

Definition 1.40 defines that (I translate loosely): a function between two measurable spaces is said to be measurable if every measurable image has a measurable inverse image.
$g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is picked so that it is measurable with respect to Borel Algebra $ (\mathbb{R}^n)$, and lemma 1.42 uses this fact.
My question: does "$g$ measurable with respect to Borel Algebra $ (\mathbb{R} ^n)$" mean that the $\sigma$-algebra for both of its domain and codomain are Borel Algebras (which are $ (\mathbb{R} ^n)$ and $ (\mathbb{R} )$ respectively)? This is the only case I can make sense out of lemma 1.42, using definition 1.40, by arguing that every open ball around a point generated by linear combination (or product) implies an open ball in the domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  a function $g:X \to \mathbb R$ is called measurable if for all real $\alpha$, the set
$\{x \in X: g(x)<\alpha\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ selected for $X$. This is equivalent to $g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal A$ for all Borel sets $B$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The definition you gave is given in that book earlier as the first definition of a measurable function, and then it defines it more generally.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but just for the purpose of information sharing, I found this answer here resolving my confusion more directly: https://discord.com/channels/268882317391429632/989612665917833226/989622708071460914